# What is boost::ptr_vector::pop_front() return type?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have a little issue using `auto_type boost::ptr_vector::pop_front()`

The return type `auto_type` is defined like this

`typedef ptr_container_detail::static_move_ptr<Ty_,Deleter> 
                                   auto_type;`

However assigning to std::auto_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, fails ...

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::ptr_container_detail::static_move_ptr<T,Deleter>' to 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>' 
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::ptr_container_detail::static_move_ptr<T,Deleter>' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>'  
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'boost::ptr_container_detail::static_move_ptr<T,Deleter>' to 'std::tr1::weak_ptr<_Ty>'
```

By looking to the implementation it looks like `pop_front` should return a smart pointer to front and return that value.

```
auto_type pop_front()  
{  
    BOOST_ASSERT( !this->empty() &&  
                  "'pop_front()' on empty container" );   
    auto_type ptr( static_cast<value_type>( this->base().front() ) );   
                                 // nothrow   
    this->base().pop_front();    // nothrow  
    return ptr_container_detail::move( ptr );   
}
```

But .. what type is that `auto_type` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of auto_type as a non-copyable form of  std::auto_ptr. Notice that when you release an object, the pointer is removed from the container and the containers size shrinks. For containers that store nulls, we can exploit that auto_type is convertible to bool:

```
if( ptr_vector< nullable<T> >::auto_type r = vec.pop_back() )
{
  ...
}
```